# How to dismiss touch ID after success or failure

Tags: ios8, touch-id

Currently I don't have a Touch ID enabled device to test with. That's why I am asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

You do not get to dismiss it. You dont have a reference to the alert.

The system takes over until the user cancels, fails or chooses the alternate method.